# C++: Callback in class

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012, callback, typelib

I have a bit complicated class.

In this class I have a reference:

```
Private:
        IEtApiPtr _pIEtApi;
```

IEtApiPtr is defined in a .tlh file:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IEtApi, __uuidof(IEtApi));
```

IEtApiPtr has a void named "SetRawDataCB"

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetRawDataCB (
    /*[in]*/ long address,
    /*[in]*/ long userData,
    /*[out,retval]*/ enum ApiError * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

I have defined a callback function in the class:

```
void CETAPI::RawDataCB(RawData& r, void* userData)
{
    //do something
}
```

Now I want to install a callback using

```
_pIEtApi->SetRawDataCB((long)(__int64)(&RawDataCB),0,&result);
```

... the compiler tells me "Error C2276: Invalid operation for expression of a bound member function".

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because `RawDataCB` is a member function not a global function. You can declare `RawDataCB` as a static function in the class as follows and this will work. However you will no longer have access to the `this` pointer (i.e. no member variables) unless you add it as a parameter to `RawDataCB` and perhaps make `RawDataCB` a friend to gain access to private data of the class as a member function would have. This can be done by updating the function declaration as follows:

```
class CETAPI {
  static void RawDataCB(RawData& r, void* userData);
};
```

Alternatively, you can pass a pointer to `RawDataCB` as a member function pointer rather than a function pointer. Member function pointers can be manipulated as follows, so you will just pass an object of type `RawDataCBType` to `SetRawDataCB`.

```
typedef void (CETAPI::*RawDataCBType)(RawData&, void*); // typedef the member function pointer type
RawDataCBType pmf = &CETAPI::RawDataCB; // create and initialize a pointer to the member function
pCETAPIObject->*pmf(r, userData); // call the member function on an object of type CETAPI
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) is a good article that talks about member pointers.

Comment: Can I not declare the callback within the class itself? Or in other words: Can I say myClass->CreateCallback(); and the class itself would create a callback in itself?

Comment: @tmighty When you declare the function inside the class it has a different signature than when you declare it outside the class (unless you declare it inside the class using the static keyword). This is because declaring a function inside the class makes it a non-static member function. Non-static member functions are different than global functions, they have different signatures making pointers to them pointers to a different type. Member functions have access to per-object local variables.

Comment: @tmighty They have this because they are implicitly passed the ‘this’ pointer, a pointer to the object the member function is being invoked upon. The issue is further complicated because your function is virtual, and you really do need a this pointer because the this pointer will point to something containing a pointer to the virtual table, which is needed at runtime to resolve the actual function being called.

Comment: @tmighty In your case I’m guessing the piece of code using the call back is not going to have the definition of what IEtApiPtr points to, so you really can't have this be a non-static member function and certainly not a virtual function. My advice: try removing the virtual keyword from the function declaration, and try adding the static keyword to the declaration. Adding the static keyword makes the function signature the same as a global function, the only difference is the function will have access to static member data (per class, but not per object data).

Comment: I could not remove the "virtual" keyword because the declaration is located in a .tlb / .tlh file, and I can not modify it :-(

Comment: @tmighty  that’s too bad, and no problem glad to help. I don’t know all the details of your code and what you really need here on a higher level, but it’s possible you could work around this by defining another function in your own source which acts as a proxy, that is you pass it as the callback and it calls the member function though _pIEtApi.

Comment: @tmighty  The other thing I notice here is you’re casting the pointer to an 8-byte __int64 and then truncating it to a 4-byte long. Casting the function to an int in the first place is not overly safe, but if you’re running on 64-bit you’re losing part of your pointer, and if you have a pointer larger than 4-billion or so you’re losing part of it. So if this compiles, I think it will crash when the callback is used.

Comment: @tmighty  However in 32-bit you may be fine. Since you’re casting away type information, you should verify what SetRawDataCB is expecting for parameters, perhaps in the documentation of where ever the .tlb/tlh files are from, and ensure perhaps with the debugger or print statements that the callback functionality is working as expected. After this is verified I would then implement the functionality you actually need within the callback.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible that I send you the code that I have so far so that you can take a look at it?

Comment: @tmighty, I'm not overly versed in COM, but it's possible something might jump out at me. I'm not sure I want to leave my email here, but I'd be happy to take a look, I'm not sure how to get it to pop up but I saw an chat option here a couple days ago, I could leave it there. I'm not sure when time will permit however, but if I have the source I'll probably peek at it within the next week at least.

Comment: Thank you for your offer. Due to time reasons I have chosen a different approach now.

Answer (score 0):

In This case compiler founds problem in the syntax
use following line of code

*pIEtApi->SetRawDataCB((long)(*_int64)(&CETAPI::RawDataCB),0,&result);

see the link for more info [Error code description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/850cstw1.aspx)